# What is batchSize mongodb curor

Tags: mongodb

I am WOrking With mongodb cursor and there is this thing batch which is not quite understandable for me, as i know it determines how much documents should be returned for each batch, by default it is 101 which is 4mb (as i know)

but what does each batch means? so if i create cursor it will only result 101 document? what if i have million document in my schema? what does it do exactly?

code:

```
 const cursor = await Model.aggregate([]).cursor().exec();

 cursor.eachAsync((doc)=>{})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most applications iterate result sets one document at a time, as your code shows:

```
 cursor.eachAsync((doc)=>{})
```

It is however very inefficient to retrieve documents one at a time from the server.

*Batch size* is how many documents the driver requests from the server at once. Larger batch size reduces overhead but increases memory consumption on the application side. A batch size that is too big can perform worse, so simply increasing batch size indefinitely is generally not desirable.

From the application's standpoint, changing batch size does not generally change how application would work, or how it is written.

Comment: so is it recommended to use default batch size? because i now use 5000 and it would be very memory inefficient right?

Comment: Unless you have a specific problem you are trying to solve, leave the batch size at its default.